# Mi arreglo se encuentra vacío al asignarle los datos de mi respuesta subscribe, Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Tengo el siguiente código:

> component.ts

```
  paisSuc: any = {};
  estadosSuc: any = [];

  loadPaisSucursal(pais_name: string) {
    console.log("1",pais_name);
    this.lugaresService.getPaisName(pais_name).subscribe(
      res=> {
        this.paisSuc = res;
        console.log("2",this.paisSuc);
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
    console.log("3 ",this.paisSuc);
    this.lugaresService.getEstadosWhitPais(this.paisSuc.id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.estadosSuc = res;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
```

El problema es que el arreglo **paisSuc** no está recibiendo nada, lo verifique con el **console.log("3 ",this.paisSuc);** que está afuera del subscribe, pero con el **console.log("2 ",this.paisSuc);** que tengo dentro del subscribe me aparecen los datos que quiero guardar en el arreglo, por lo que llegue a la conclusión de que solo se guardan temporalmente o algo, ¿podrían aclararme qué estoy haciendo mal?

Les dejo una imagen de lo que me aparece en consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que el cuerpo del suscribe se ejecuta de forma asíncrona. Cuando el código se ejecuta y llega al suscribe, se inicia el proceso de obtener los datos en segundo plano, luego continúa la ejecución del código y llega al console log 3 antes de que los datos estén listos por eso no tiene nada aún. Si quieres usar los datos debes hacerlo dentro del suscribe, donde está el console log 2

Comment: Es algo raro ya que en mis otro métodos están iguales y esos sí funcionaban bien, ahora voy a modificarlos para que no vaya a pasar lo mismo, muchas gracias